# I started using a static. subdomain but YSlow still says I am not cookie-free?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, yslow

I changed all my static content references to use the `static.` subdomain instead of `www.` but YSlow still says I am not using cookie-free domains for my static content.  What else do I need to do?

Example: http://www.justineyandlephotography.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What else do I need to do?

To be completely cookie-free, you should use a different domain, not subdomain because cookies can be shared between subdomains. For example take a look at how Stack Overflow does it:

- main domain: `stackoverflow.com`
- cookie free domain for static resources: `sstatic.net`

So in your case:

- main domain: `www.justineyandlephotography.com`
- cookie free domain for static resources: `anything that doesn't end up with justineyandlephotography.com`

It basically means that you need to purchase an additional domain if you don't already have one.

Comment: The hosting company I use only allows for a single domain.  Can I configure the second domain as a pointer?

Comment: You have saved me hours or who knows maybe days of researching why cookies were being sent. And to answer a possible solution: Use a CDN that has a completely different hostname than your website. This also helps load your pages quicker! Unfortunately, our website is www.lynda.com and we get CDN from cdn.lynda.com so there's cookies getting sent with every request to get static content. Unless we change the cookie's domain to be www.lynda.com, but that could open the door for a whole set of different issues

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an additional domain, you can use sub domain. And yslow will not detect it, if you are using cloudflare or any other CDN which sends a cookie with every request.